# Php Phalcon, как добавить робота к пользователю?

Tags: php, phalcon

Есть две модели пользователи и роботы, установил связь между ними как один ко многим:

```
class Users extends Model
{
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $about;
    public $email;
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->hasMany(
              "id",
              "Robots",
              "users_id"
               );
    }
class Robots extends Model
{
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $type;
    public $year;
    public $users_id;
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->belongsTo(
            "users_id",
            "Users",
            "id"
        );
    }
}
```

Контроллёр:

```
 public function addAction()
 {
     if ($this->request->isGet()) {
         $this->tag->prependTitle("Добавить робота :: ");
         }
     if ($this->request->isPost()) {        
         $user = Users::findFirst($this->session->get("auth-id"));
         $robot = new Robots();
         $robot->name = $this->request->getPost("name");
         $robot->type = $this->request->getPost("type");
         $robot->year = $this->request->getPost("year");
         $robot->users_id = $user;  
         if ($robot->save()) {
             $this->flashSession->success("Вы добавили нового робота !");
             return $this->response->redirect([
                  "for" => "user-show",
                  "name" => $this->session->get("auth-name")
             ]);
          } else {
              foreach ($robot->getMessages() as $message) {
                  echo $message, "<br/>";
              }
         }
    }
}
```

Проверял содержимое переменной `$robot` перед сохранением, поле `id`, `users_id` отправляются не заполненными. Я правильно понимаю поле `id` автоинкрементивное и заполняется при попадании в базу данных, но поле `users_id` должно содержать `id` пользователя и именно в этом и дело. Подскажите почему `users_id` передаётся пустым, либо почему не добавляется робот ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Передайте в `users_id` не весь обьет пользователя а только `id`

`$robot->users_id = $user->id;`